# three.js animation logic for spinning cuboids

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'm trying to create a cuboid from 5 cuboids one of top of the other - that rotates 180 CW degrees every two seconds.

It's kinda working but I'm not getting smooth results... I thought a good strategy would be that during the rotating period- the z-position of the top-left and top-right vertices of a single face will be compared- if they are the same then it's time to stop the rotating period.

The problem is that the difference between the vertices is never zero.. it's very close to zero... so I check if it's in a margin of 0.1 and thus I have a problem with the beginning of a rotation that is jammed because sometimes it's less than 0.1. Also sometimes the rotations continue when they should stop because the difference is not less than 0.1.

```
var spinningPeriod = false, counter = 0, lastTime = 0;
function animate(){
    counter++;
    var time = (new Date()).getTime();
    var timeDiff = time - lastTime;
    var angleChange = 0.2 * timeDiff * 2 * Math.PI / 1000;

    if (counter%200==0 && counter > 0) {
        spinningPeriod = true;
    }
    if (spinningPeriod) {
       var v1 = cubes[0].geometry.vertices[0].clone();
       var v2 = cubes[0].geometry.vertices[3].clone();
       cubes[0].updateMatrixWorld();
       cubes[0].localToWorld(v1);
       cubes[0].localToWorld(v2);

       if (Math.abs(v1.x - v2.x) < 0.1) {
            spinningPeriod = false;
       } 

       for (var ii =0; ii<5; ++ii) {
        cubes[ii].rotation.y += angleChange;
       }
    }
    lastTime = time;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    // request new frame
    requestAnimationFrame(function(){
        animate();
    });
  }

  // renderer
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  // camera
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.z = 500;

  // scene
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();


  // cube
  var cubes = new Array();
  var currentHeight = -150;
  for (var ii =0; ii<5; ++ii) {
    cubes[ii] = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(400, 50, 20));
    currentHeight += 50;
    cubes[ii].position.y = currentHeight;
    cubes[ii].overdraw = true;
    scene.add(cubes[ii]);
  }

  // start animation
  animate();
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree, looking at the position is probably not the best way to do it. If you're concerned with the angle, then the angle should be your focus. Basically you want to have your test be based on the spin vs a max spin - when you're more than that, stop and adjust as needed (in this case, it was sometimes > 1 with the amount of angleChange, so I just reset it to 1).

Instead of your animate function above, try this one - it looks like it works pretty reliably for me.

```
var spinningPeriod = false, counter = 0, lastTime = 0;
var spinAngle = 0, spinMax = 1 * Math.PI;
function animate(){
    counter++;
    var time = (new Date()).getTime(),
        timeDiff = time - lastTime,
        speed = 0.2 * 2 * Math.PI / 1000,
        angleChange = speed * timeDiff;

    if (counter%200==0 && counter > 0) {
        spinningPeriod = true;
        spinAngle = 0;
    }
    console.log(counter, spinningPeriod, cubes[0].rotation.y / Math.PI);
    if (spinningPeriod) {
        spinAngle += angleChange;
        if (spinAngle > spinMax) {
            spinningPeriod = false;
            spinAngle = spinMax;
        }
        for (var ii =0; ii<5; ++ii) {
            cubes[ii].rotation.y = spinAngle;
        }
    }
    lastTime = time;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    // request new frame
    requestAnimationFrame(function(){
        animate();
    });
}
```